# How do you use apply_impulse correctly?

Tags: python, physics, pymunk

I'm just starting out with the PyMunk physics library. I'm having trouble using `apply_impulse()`. I'm calling it like this:

```
player.body.apply_impulse(player.body, (10,10), (10,10) )
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> > TypeError: apply_impulse() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Why is this and what's the correct way to call `apply_impulse()`?

Comment: not that i know anything about pymunk, but why are you passing player.body to a function within player.body? and furthermore, maybe player.body itself is two arguments?

Comment: Because the first variable of apply_impulse is a reference to self. No, player.body is one variable, it's the 'rigidbody' of player. That is, the class that contains the physics functions for the object.

Comment: This is strange. I've used PyMunk before, and the code looked OK so I looked up the [documentation](http://pymunk.googlecode.com/svn/tags/pymunk-1.0.0/docs/api/index.html) which shows that you are indeed doing the right stuff. Possibly the documentation is outdated? Could you post the actual function, "apply_impulse()" from the library you are currently using?

Comment: The first argument is "self", which you need not specify explicitly. "self" is always the first parameter within methods to that particular class. Try removing player.body.

Comment: but when you call a function on an object you don't need to pass the object itself. `self` is in the function definition but you don't need to pass it when you call the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a member function on its object you usually don't need to pass the object itself as the first parameter. `self` is in the function definition of every member function but not in the function call.

see this post:
[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Comment: That was it, thanks. Silly me. You know what though, as a Python beginning programmer, the documentation was a little confusing on that. I mean, it's saying 'Call function x with params y and z' when you actually need to call function x with param z alone. That gets confusing. /rant Anyways, thanks for straightening it out for me. :)

Comment: NP I agree that from a syntactic viewpoint it doesn't make much sense. However it is there to deal with some other ambiguity issues that you'll probably discover when you become more familiar with object-oriented programming, at which point you're likely to appreciate the clarity granted by this approach. :)